# Where do built-in methods come from?

Tags: javascript, methods, built-in

I've been studying about JS objects and I faced the description of methods. It says that a method is "a shorthand for a function assigned to the method's name". In other words, a method is a function, right? But the thing is, where do the methods like parseInt() and toLocaleString() come from if I haven't created a function to turn a float-point number into a integer?
I googled about built-in functions, but I haven't found any documentation answering this question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects

Comment: These are part of the browser's  or node.js JavaScript implementation.

Answer (score 0):

They are *built into* the js engine, i.e. it does provide the implementation and creates the function (method) in the environment before running any JS code.